# Ocaml function that from a matrix produces a modified matrix

Tags: arrays, ocaml

So i have this little function:

```ml
let switch matrix =
  for i = 0 to Array.length matrix - 1 do
    for j = 0 to Array.length (Array.get matrix i) - 1 do
      if Array.get (Array.get matrix i) j = false then
        Array.set (Array.get matrix i) j true
    done
  done;;
```

Which basically flips all false values in a matrix to true value. This is not what im really going for, it's just to illustrate what ive tried so far.

The problem is is this function changes the values of the matrix instead of creating a matrix.

I actually need it to be a :  bool array array -> bool array array =

What do i need to do in order to have a function that does that.

I've thought of pattern matching, so i've tried:

```ml
let switch matrix =
  for i = 0 to Array.length matrix - 1 do
    for j = 0 to Array.length (Array.get matrix i) - 1 do
      match Array.get (Array.get matrix i) j with true -> true | false -> true
    done
  done;;
```

But this function says: his expression should have type unit.

Sorry if this is a stupid question, i just started with OCaml

EDIT:  So, i tried this:

```ml
let switch matrix =
  let newMatrix =
    Array.make_matrix (Array.length matrix)
      (Array.length (Array.get matrix 1))
      true
  in
  let switching matrixes = matrixes.(0).(0) <- false in
  switching newMatrix;
  newMatrix;;
```

but now, it's of type a array array -> bool array array = . But i need it to be bool array array -> bool array array. What can i do to move forward from this?

Comment: Why do you use `Array.get matrix 1` instead of `matrix.(1)` which does the same ?

Comment: Don't be afraid of more generic types than you need. `'a array array` is just fine. If this is going into a module you can narrow the type in the mli file or annotate the function as `let switch (matrix : bool array array)`. But don't do that prematurely. As soon as you use this in real code where you check the contents of the original matrix the compiler will deduce it's a `bool array array` on it's own. PS: Using a nested `Array.init` might be faster than creating a new matrix and modifying it.

Comment: @Butanium i just didn't realize that that was the thing at the time ahaha

Answer (score 2):

Given that there are only two options for a boolean value (true or false) if you have a matrix of boolean values and want to flip the false values to true, you will always end up with a matrix full of true values.

This greatly simplifies your code.

```
let switch matrix =
  Array.(
    let height = length matrix in
    let width  = length matrix.(0) in
    make_matrix width height true
  )
```

If your goal is actually to flip true to false and false to true:

```
let switch matrix =
  Array.(
    map (map not) matrix
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution after the edit is good. You just need to apply your first function (the one that modifies the matrix in place) to the new matrix you created.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from your first piece of code :

```ml
let switch matrix = for i = 0 to (Array.length matrix - 1) do 
    for j = 0 to ((Array.length (Array.get matrix i ))-1) do
             if Array.get (Array.get matrix i) j = false then Array.set (Array.get matrix i) j true
        done;
    done;
```

Formatting it properly and using the `.()` and `.() <-` operators for `Array.get` `Array.set` :

```ml
let switch matrix =
  for i = 0 to Array.length matrix - 1 do
    for j = 0 to Array.length matrix.(i) - 1 do
      if not matrix.(i).(j) then matrix.(i).(j) <- true
    done
  done
```

`if expr = true` is equivalent to `if expr` and `if expr = false` is equivalent to `if not expr`

Then creating a new matrix at the beginning of your code filled with `true`, modifying it according to `matrix` and returning it, we get :

```ml
let switch matrix =
  let n = Array.length matrix in 
  let p = Array.length (matrix.(0)) in
  let result = Array.make_matrix n p true in
  for i = 0 to n - 1 do
    for j = 0 to p - 1 do
      if matrix.(i).(j) then result.(i).(j) <- false
    done
  done;
  result
```

Comment: Don't hesitate to edit directly the question if it's just for formatting and won't change the question asked